# Filter a result based on a parameter from another table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two tables in an Excel spreadsheet. In one I store the ID, name and score of the employees (currently the score column is empty).

[image]

And I have another table, in which I have the IDs and the scores.

I need a formula to fill the first table with the scores, using the ID as a reference.

Expected result:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Vlookup, Xlookup, INDEX/MATCH will all do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in cell C3, per your screenshot), then drag it down to C7:

```
=iferror(index($F$3:$f$5, match(A3, $E$3: $E$5,0)),"")
```